# Android ListView using SQLite

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to populate listview within a fragment class. I am trying to query that for every one student he has many toDo's s. When the user is logged on I want to retrieve all his ToDo's he uniquely added and only data that belongs to him will be shown.

Here is my Controls for notes to retrieve all notes

```
private DatabaseHelper help;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Cursor listNotes() {
        Cursor c = db.query(help.NOTE_TABLE, new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE}, help.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(help.NOTES_ID)} , null, null, null);
        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }

        return c;
     }
```

My databasehelper is the class that only creates tables. Why is it when I try to get the data it is a null pointer, here is my populateList method.

```
    public void populateList(){
    Cursor cursor = execute.listNotes();

    //Mapping the fields cursor to text views
    String[] fields = new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE};
    int [] text = new int[] {R.id.item_title,R.id.item_body, R.id.item_date};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_layout,cursor, fields, text,0);

    //Calling list object instance
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

LogCat

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.app.Notes.populateList(Notes.java:49)

        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post your complete adb log trace please.

Comment: Why are you calling `c.close()` before `return c`? If you close a `Cursor` it is no longer usable (and is also possibly set to `null`).

Comment: I have removed the c.close(), still not passing my cursor to my populate list

Comment: Wouldn't `while(c != null)` create an infinite loop?

Comment: @yuttadhammo would it, how can I pass the cursor to my listview?

Comment: We really need a logcat... if the cursor is null, it means something's probably wrong with your query or the database.

Comment: Done, I am not passing the cursor correctly and setting data to textview, I have created the table correctly

Comment: db.query must be returning null. Try `Cursor c = db.query(help.NOTE_TABLE, new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: Sorry, to be sure, which line is line 49?

Comment: @yuttadhammo its still empty,  check my populate list method. Liune 49 is Cursor cursor = execute.listNotes();

Comment: Ah, should remove `execute.` I think.

Comment: How will I be able to reference the db controls to my fragment then?

Comment: Reference the class in which it appears, e.g. `Controls.listNotes`

Comment: Oh...my database control is declared as NotesControl control. Now I have Cursor cursor = control.listNotes(); but its still empty

Comment: The logcat should be different though

Comment: @yuttadhammo yes this is why I am stuck, do i need to open the db?

Comment: Your question has changed a lot since the beginning, but yes, at this point your problem is probably that you haven't opened the database using `getReadableDatabase()`

Comment: You should probably create a new question with your new problem in it, otherwise this will get messy. I've answered your problem in this question already.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the cursor before accessing any data. You'll need to put the data you're looking for into an object and then return that object. Don't return the cursor.

```
public MyObject listNotes() {
    Cursor c = db.query("YOUR_QUERY");
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        obj.setParameter(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("column_name")));
    }
    c.close();
    return obj;
 }
```

This is assuming of course that the first element of your cursor is the item your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your reference to the `listNotes` function. `execute` doesn't have a function called listNotes, so that is what is returning as `null`

You need to reference the actual class in which listNotes appears, e.g. `Controls.listNotes();`