# Android - populate ListView SQLite, cursor null pointer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have two tables atm, users and notes. I am trying to retrieve data that belongs to the user. So all data to list must be owned by the original user and shown only to him. I have made my table in Databasehelper.
I have made a new class that controls the notes table. In listNotes() I want to loop through the cursor row and get all data owned by the user. Am I quering it correctly?

```
// Listing all notes

public Cursor listNotes() {

    Cursor c = db.query(help.NOTE_TABLE, new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
   return c;

 }
```

I then want to display the cursor data collected in a listview

```
public void populateList(){

    Cursor cursor = control.listNotes();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);

    //Mapping the fields cursor to text views
    String[] fields = new String[]{help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE};
    int [] text = new int[] {R.id.item_title,R.id.item_body, R.id.item_date};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_layout,cursor, fields, text,0);

    //Calling list object instance
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ListView using SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903352/android-listview-using-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating the `NOTE_TABLE` right.
You miss a space and a comma here

```
+ COLUMN_DATE + "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
```

It has to be

```
+ COLUMN_DATE + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

One is you have missed a comma (after the Timestamp as specified in an earlier answer).

The other error you have is when using a SimpleCursorAdapter, you need to ensure that the Projection string array includes something to index the rows uniquely and this must be an integer column named as "_id". SQLite already has a feature built in for this and provides a column named "_id" for this purpose (however you can have your own integer column which you can rename to _id). To solve this, change your projection string array to something like:

```
new String[] {"ROW_ID AS _id", help.COLUMN_TITLE,help.COLUMN_BODY, help.COLUMN_DATE}
```

I guess the NullPointerException stems from this (but without the stacktrace I don't know for sure).

Comment: I think Im retrieving the data Cursor wrong in my populate method

Comment: Can you show which line throws the NPE and also the stacktrace?